# Keep both the regex matches and the text between them

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to create an equation parser in javascript, so I'm using regex to break the equation into its individual parts. Here is the regex that I am using at the moment:

```
var equation_string = '!#$123+456';
var operator = '(!|=|<|>)=|[=<>()^\\/*+-]';
var number = '(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)([eE][-+]?\\d+)?';
var variable = '[A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*';
var separator = ',';
var other = '\\S+';
var whitespace = '\\s+';

var pattern = new RegExp(number+'|'+operator+'|'+variable+'|'+separator+'|'+other+'|'+whitespace, 'g');

var equation_parts = equation_string.match(pattern);
```

I want to keep all parts of the equation (for tracking where I need to highlight in the equation if it is malformed). But it runs into a problem if the user was to enter say '!#$123+456', which due to the '\S+' gives me a single part '!#$123+456', when it should be '!#$','123','+','456'.

I could set other to '\S', but this would be '!','#','$','123','+','456', but I would prefer to keep all the "other" type patterns together.

What's the best way of keeping the "other" type patterns together? Or is there a way for me to drop the "other" pattern and have the regex return both the matched patterns and all the text between them?

Comment: My instinct would be to change other to explicitly disallow everything that's in the other regexes.

Comment: Setting `other` to `\S` would also be my answer to this problem, since it effectively check at every position to see if it is a valid token before it take the character. Otherwise, you have to duplicate the `number|operator|variable|separator` inside a negative look-ahead to achieve the same result.

Comment: I thought of negating all the other patterns, but was hoping there would be an elegant alternative. If there isn't, then I will probably just use '\S'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use lookahead assertions so that it will only match if nothing else does:

```
(
    (?!(!|=|<|>)=|[=<>()^\\/*+-]) // this is the pattern for "operator", enclosed in a negative lookahead
    (?!(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)([eE][-+]?\\d+)?) // the pattern for "number"...
    (?![A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*) // "variable"...
    (?!,) // "separator"...
    (?!\s) // "whitespace"
    . // no other pattern matches, so it's ok to consume the next character.
)* // repeat this as often as possible.
```

---

The other solution is not to match `other` characters at all, doing something along the lines of this:

```
var match_index= 0;
while ((match = pattern.exec(equation_string)) !== null)
{
    if(match.index > match_index)
    {
        var other= equation_string.substring(match_index, match.index);
        alert(other);
    }
    match_index= pattern.lastIndex;
}
if (match_index < equation_string.length){
    var other= equation_string.substring(match_index);
    alert(other);
}
// result: "!#$"
```

Comment: Your second solution is pretty much what I want, I modified it so that it collects both matches and others. The part I'm not sure about is why the '!==null' is needed in the while loop? Doesn't null equate to false in this situation, or is it added purely for readability?

Comment: @Ayb4btu: The `!== null` is there because I'm not very experienced with JavaScript - it worked this way, so I went with it :)